# CakePHP 4 FormProtector instance has not been created error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am currently in the process of updating a (rather big) application from CakePHP 3 to 4.

I have this template:

```
<?= $this->Form->create(
    $dmpLayer,
    [
        'url' => [
            'controller' => 'DmpLayers',
            'action' => 'edit',
        ],
    ]
); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <?= $this->element('DataLayers/layer-table'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="form-div" class="col-6">
        <div class="layer-form">
            <?= $this->element('DataLayers/form') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="layer-form">
            <h2>Form Actions</h2>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Create/Update Layer', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('data-layers'); ?>
```

which includes the `DataLayers/form` element:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h4>Artist Layer</h4>

        <?php
            echo $this->Html->tag('fieldset', $this->element(
                'actions/add',
                [
                    'url' => [
                        'prefix' => 'Admin',
                        'plugin' => false,
                        'controller' => 'SegmentCores',
                        'action' => 'add',
                    ],
                ]
            )
            . $this->Form->control('artist_layer.segment_cores[]', [
                'multiple',
                'options' => $segmentCores,
                'label'   => 'Segment Core',
                'value'   => $selectedValues['segment_cores'],
            ])
            . $this->Form->control('artist_layer.segment_potentials[]', [
                'multiple',
                'options' => $segmentPotentials,
                'label'   => 'Segment Potential',
                'value'   => $selectedValues['segment_potentials'],
            ])
            . $this->Form->control('artist_layer.layer_tags[]', [
                'multiple',
                'options' => $layerTags,
                'label'   => 'Artist Tag',
                'value'   => $selectedValues['artist_tags'],
            ])
            . $this->Form->control('artist_layer.genres[]', [
                'empty'   => 'No genre set',
                'options' => $genres,
                'label'   => 'Genre',
                'value'   => $selectedValues['genres'],
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

$this->Form->unlockField('artist_layer.genres');
$this->Form->unlockField('artist_layer.segment_cores');
$this->Form->unlockField('artist_layer.segment_potentials');
$this->Form->unlockField('artist_layer.layer_tags');

?>
```

In the `initialize` function of the `AppController` I have this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Security');
```

When I visit the page, it doesn't render and I immediately get this error:

```
FormProtector instance has not been created. Ensure you have loaded the FormProtectionComponent in your controller and called FormHelper::create() before calling FormHelper::unlockField()
```

This is the only form in my application for which this error happens. Every other form is working fine, and I am calling the `Form->unlockField()` function in many of them.
I am obviously calling `Form->create()` in my code, so is this because I am including an element to add fields to the form that is defined in the "main" template? Or is there some other explanation?

I have already attempted adding

```
$this->loadComponent('FormProtection');
```

to my `AppController`, but this causes a whole lot more problems in many other places in the app, and it doesn't solve the problem anyway (the page renders, but I get an error when submitting the form to save the data).

Comment: Whether it's because its in an element is something that you can easily check by putting the code directly in your template instead of using the element, or by simply removing it (it's rather unlikely as they share the same view instance). You should also check the exception's stack trace to figure which `unlockField()` call the error exactly originates from, to make sure it's not from somewhere that you didn't expect.

Comment: @ndm the error comes indeed from the first `unlockField` call in the `DataLayers/form` element. I also tried copypasting the code in the main template instead of using the element and I get the same error.

Comment: Generally the security component should work fine, while it's deprecated, its form protection functionality is still intact. The error messages encourages upgrading, but it's not technically necessary. I'd suggest that you debug the request both in your controller action, as well as your template, to figure whether the required `formTokenData` attribute is being set correctly by the security component, and that it's not being lost somewhere along the way: `debug($this->request->getAttribute('formTokenData'));`

Comment: @ndm I did debug the request inside CakePHP's FormHelper and found out that when it's called by another random form, the `formTokenData` attribute is present, while it's not there in this specific form that's causing the error. But I don't get why, as I'm calling 'Form->create()' in both templates. I even printed the stacktrace inside the FormHelper, and it's exactly the same (minus the different template of course), so it doesn't seem like there are any extra or missing methods in any of the two calls.

Comment: As suggested, debug in your controller action too, to figure whether the attribute is possibly being lost at some point, or never present to begin with. For more exact results, debug inside of the security component to, maybe it's not being set there in the first place.